# How to run an R code within a given duration and then stop it?

Tags: r, rselenium

Currently I'm working on a web crawler project with Rselenium, which needs to open about 100,000 webpages in turn and do the info collection :

```
url <- paste0("www.111", r0[ii],".com")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
```

Seems that the most time-consuming portion of this process is opening a new webpage, especially loading ads, external links, etc. So how could I run this kind of R code within a specific duration (e.g., 2 seconds) and then stop it, and run the following info collection process? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to stop ? Is it only one function that you want to stop after 2 seconds if not finished ? or do you run several functions and want to stop the list of functions after 2seconds, and start the new list of functions on a new url ?

Comment: I'd like to continue running following functions like `content <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]][1]) %>% html_nodes("#aaa") %>% html_text()` after run (and stop after 2 seconds) `remDr$navigate(url)`. The function `remDr$navigate(url)` is the only one function that I want to stop after 2 seconds if not finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I withTimeout from R.utils seems to do what you want (interrupting a function after a delay).

```
library(R.utils)
A=2
foo <- function() {
while(A>1){print(A)}
}

#foo()#Ridiculous infinite function don't run it

withTimeout(foo(),timeout=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! The `R.utils` package does work. Seems that the function `withTimeout` could be used along with the `try` function in order to continue running any following functions. e.g:

```
library(RSelenium)  
library(rvest)
library(R.utils)

remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "127.1.1.1" 
                      , port = 4444
                      , browserName = "firefox") # connect to Server
remDr$open()
try(withTimeout(remDr$navigate("https://aaaa.org"), timeout=0.5)) # stop navigation after 0.5 sec
a1 <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]][1])
a2 <- html_nodes(a1, "pre") %>% html_text()
```

Thanks!